# Execute Python script within Jupyter notebook using a specific virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I would like to execute a long running Python script from within a Jupyter notebook so that I can hack on the data structures generated mid-run.

The script has many dependencies and command line arguments and is executed with a specific virtualenv. Is it possible to interactively run a Python script inside a notebook from a specified virtualenv (different to that of the Jupyter installation)?

Comment: Another way to solve your problem is to use an IDE like PyCharm. Just choose which virtualenv you want to use for your project and add a few breakpoints. When the execution pauses at you breakpoints, you will be able to run python code interactively.

You could also take a look at pdb (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (non `conda` python):
(MacOS, brew version of python. if you are working with system python, you may (will) need prepend each command with `sudo`)

1. First activate virtualenv. If starting afresh then, e.g., you could use virtualenvwrapper:

   ```
   $ pip install virtualenvwrapper
   $ mkvirtualenv -p python2 py2env 
   $ workon py2env

   # This will activate virtualenv

   (py2env)$ 

   # Then install jupyter within the active virtualenv
   (py2env)$ pip install jupyter

   # jupyter comes with ipykernel, but somehow you manage to get an error due to ipykernel, then for reference ipykernel package can be installed using:
   (py2env)$ pip install ipykernel
   ```
2. Next, set up the kernel

   ```
   (py2env)$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name py2env --display-name "Python2 (py2env)"
   ```
3. then start jupyter notebook (the venv need not be activated for this step)

   ```
   (py2env)$ jupyter notebook
   # or
   #$ jupyter notebook
   ```

In the jupyter notebook dropdown menu: `Kernel >> Change Kernel >> <list of kernels>` you should  see  `Python2 (py2env)` kernel.

This also makes it easy to identify python version of kernel, and maintain either side by side.

Here is the link to detailed docs:
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: Good stuff here, thanks. I wanted to mention that the first time I did the ipykernel install step, it didn't take. Not sure what happened (other than nothing). The second time I ran it, I got the message that the kernel had been created.

Answer (score 47):

A bit more simple solution to get notebook kernels available in other notebooks.

I'm using Linux + virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper. If you are using different setup, change some commands to the appropriate ones, but you should get the idea.

```
mkvirtualenv jupyter2
workon jupyter2
(jupyter2) pip install jupyter
(jupyter2) ipython kernel install --name "jupyter2_Python_2" --user
```

last command creates `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/jupyter2\ python\ 2/` directory

same stuff for 3

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 jupyter3
// this uses python3 as default python in virtualenv
workon jupyter3
(jupyter3) pip install jupyter
(jupyter3) ipython kernel install --name "jupyter3_Python_3" --user
```

When done you should see both kernels, no matter what env are you using to start jupyter.
You can delete links to kernels directly in `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/`.
To specify location provide options to `ipython kernel install (--help)` or just copy directories from `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/` to `~/envs/jupyter3/share/jupyter` if you want to run multiple kerenels from one notebook only.

Answer (score 16):

I found this link to be very useful:

https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/09/01/ipython_kernel/

Make sure that you pip install jupyter into your virtualenv. In case the link goes away later, here's the gist:

You need to create a new kernel. You specify your kernel with a JSON file. Your kernels are usually located at `~/.ipython/kernels`. Create a directory with the name of your virtualenv and create your kernel.json file in it. For instance, one of my paths looks like `~./ipython/kernels/datamanip/kernel.json`

Here's what my kernel.json file looks like:

```
{
  "display_name": "Data Manipulation (Python2)",
  "language": "python",
  "codemirror_mode": {
    "version": 3,
    "name":"ipython"
  },
  "argv": [
    "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/datamanip/bin/python",
    "-c",
    "from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import main; main()",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
    ]
}
```

I am not certain exactly what the codemirror_mode object is doing, but it doesn't seem to do any harm.

Comment: Not sure if you are still on SO and active.  Any chance you can provide the  gist link you mentioned?

Comment: I had to manually change the path for the python binary to the one for my newly-created virtual environment.

Answer (score 9):

It is really simple, based on the [documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs/)

You can use a virtualenv for your IPython notebook. Follow the following steps, actually no need for step one, just make sure you activated your virtualenv via `source ~/path-to-your-virtualenv/`

1. Install the ipython kernel module into your virtualenv

   workon my-virtualenv-name  # activate your virtualenv, if you haven't already
   pip install ipykernel
2. (*The most important step*) Now run the kernel "self-install" script:

   python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
   Replacing the --name parameter as appropriate.
3. You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: `Kernel -> Change kernel` and be able to switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

Comment: For step 1, do you pip install ipython kernel using the pip in your scripts folder of your virtual env? For step 2, do you run the scripts using the python.exe found in the script folder of your virtual env? For step 3, from which directory must you run your notebook?

Answer (score 6):

@singer's solution didn't work for me. Here's what worked:

```
. /path/to/virtualenv/.venv/bin/activate
python -m ipykernel install --user --name .venv --display-name .venv
```

Reference: [Kernels for different environments](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/7c12b021ee7bdcaf8cec814a624203d8e74aab08/docs/source/install/kernel_install.rst#kernels-for-different-environments) (official docs)

Comment: also at ``ipython.readthedocs`` http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html  .. for up-to-date reference

Comment: Yeah that's an up-to-date reference, but if the text changes then my reference will be invalid. So that's why I gave a git link.

Comment: sorry didn't check your link :(

Answer (score 1):

the nb_canda is useful:

```
conda install nb_conda
```

so,you can create and select your own python kernel with conda virtual environment,and manage the packages in venv

### Screenshots

List item

[image: Screenshot]

conda environment manager Conda tab in jupyter notebook allows you to manage your environments right from within your notebook.

Change Kernel
You can also select which kernel to run a notebook in by using the Change kernel option in Kernel menu