# jupyter notebook running kernel in different env

Tags: python, package, jupyter, conda, virtual-environment

I've gotten myself into some kind of horrible virtualenv mess.  Help?!

I manage environments with `conda`.  Until recently, I only had a python2 jupyter notebook kernel, but I decided to drag myself kicking and screaming into the 21st century and installed a python3 kernel; I forget how I did it.

My main (anaconda) python defaults to 2.7.

So here I am, merrily trying to use beautiful soup from inside my shiny new python3 kernel, and I don't seem to be able to do anything to get at whatever environment it's finding packages in.  Viz (all from notebook):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

-> ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Ok, fine, I'll install it using shell magic.  Right?  Right?

```
! pip install bs4

--> Collecting bs4
  Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bs4)
[...]
Successfully built bs4
Installing collected packages: bs4
Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

-> ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Oh no.  Does it think I'm in a 2.7 env even though I'm running a python3 kernel?  That won't do.

```
! conda info --envs
--> # conda environments:
#
flaskenv                 /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/envs/flaskenv
mesa                     /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/envs/mesa
py35                     /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/envs/py35
root                  *  /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda
```

Ok, I can fix that. One of those is a 3.5 env.

```
! source activate py35
--> prepending /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/envs/py35/bin to PATH

! conda install beautifulsoup4
--> Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda:
#
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py27_0
```

concerning...

```
! pip install bs4
--> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bs4 in /Users/[MY-USER]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

more concerning...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

-> ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

ARRGH!!!  *headdesk*  Am I going to have to kill the kernel in order to fix this (and re-run a bit of work)?  Is killing the kernel even going to work?  How do I get my jupyter kernel to know what environment it's supposed to be running under?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Python script within Jupyter notebook using a specific virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv)

Comment: +1 for headdesk - exactly how I have been for the last 2 days with Tensorboard and Jupyter and ... oh, the humanity!

Comment: Funny into to question made me laugh, "I've gotten myself into some kind of horrible virtualenv mess"

Answer (score 185, accepted):

This is a tricky part of ipython / Jupyter. The set of kernels available are independent of what your virtualenv is when you start jupyter Notebook. The trick is setting up the the ipykernel package in the environment you want to identify itself uniquely to jupyter. From [docs on multiple ipykernels](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments),

```
source activate ENVNAME
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name ENVNAME --display-name "Python (whatever you want to call it)"
```

If you only want to have a single Python 3 kernel, from the conda environment, just use `python -m ipykernel install --user` and it will reset the default python to the one in the virtualenv.

And yes, you will need to restart the kernel and re-run the prior steps.

See Also [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook/)

Comment: I also found that I hadn't installed jupyter into the new environment, but it still launched with the 'juptyer notebook' command. So, I didn't realize it at first.

Comment: It works but I don't get how Jupyter then finds the path to the environment. It is not mentioned in the kernel.json file.

Answer (score 13):

@tschundler's solution works perfectly if your environment has already been created.

If you want to change the default kernel at the creation of your virtual environment and avoid any manual configuration, you just need to add `jupyter` at the end of the conda command:

`conda create --name ENVNAME python=PYTHONVERSION jupyter`

The correct kernel will then be used when you use ipython or jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 10):

In my case somehow jupyter wasn't able to 'pick' the virtual environment's python. So I had to edit `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/{my_env_name}/kernel.json`
and add path to the interpreter

in the `argv` key.

Comment: If I could upvote this 5 times I would. I have Visual Studio Code, with Windows Subsystem as its console, I installed a virtualenv, then a jupyter, then I could not use libraries from the virtualenv. This solved it!!

Comment: do you have to replace the first argument of argv? tt stilll didnt seem to work....how does jupyter get notified about it?

Comment: I can see the `jupyter` folder but there is no `kernels` under it.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an easy way here

```
workon my-virtualenv-name  # activate your virtualenv, if you haven't already
pip install tornado==4.5.3
pip install ipykernel==4.8.2
```

You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: Kernel -> Change kernel and be able to switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

This worked for me. [source](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs)

Comment: workon does- not working do you know any solution i have tried searching but it doesn't work i am using vs code

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --user ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv

Output
Installed kernelspec myenv in /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/myenv
```

and go to above directory
open kernel.json

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python", # path to your virtual environment python
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "myenv",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but nobody has mentioned [`nb_conda_kernels`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels), which was made to solve this problem. You must have it installed in the environment from which you launched the running notebook, and any other environment which has kernel/s installed (`ipykernel`, `r-irkernel`, etc ) will be available as an option (Start Preferred Kernel):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience here, in case someone made the same mistake:

**TL;DR**

In VSCode I created the virtual environment from an Ubuntu terminal but forgot to activate the WSL extension too. Once I activated the WSL extension, I was able to change the Jupyterkernel to my virtual environment.

**Full explanation**

Using VSCode I work with the WSL extension (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)). I created my virtual environment from an Ubuntu terminal [Created a new terminal and selected 'Ubuntu (WSL)'] and then went to my Jupyter notebook to change my kernel, but it did not appear in the list.

I tried the [solution proposed above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593679/19667698) of adding the path to kernel.json in my virtual environment, adapting to my case (I don't use conda) but I was surprised to see that the folder `bin` in my environment did not have a file named `python`.

The solution was to activate the WSL extension: lower right corner > click on the arrows (Open a remote connection) > reopen folder in WSL.

After this, I could see in the explorer two new entries in the `bin` folder for `Python` and `Python3` (the arrow on the right side seem to indicate it's a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)).
[Virtual environment now shows the python symbolic links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1qHI.png)

Then I went to my Jupyter notebook and changed the kernel to my virtual environment.

In the end, I did not have to change the path in `kernel.json`.

P.S: The above is my understanding of my problem and the solution given my non-existing knowledge about Linux, so any comments to complement/improve this answer are very welcome!