# Unable to import pandas on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've installed both pandas and jupyter notebook on my virtualenvs(python3).
When I check `which jupyter`, it's correctly refer to my envs. However, I can't import pandas when I run it in the browser.
When I run the ipython, I can import the pandas module though...

`ImportError: No module named 'pandas'`

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jupyter is built with the Anaconda Python distribution (and the `conda` environment manager) in mind. Although some work has been done to remediate this issue, using `jupyter` with `virtualenv` is discouraged.

In this case it sounds like `jupyter` is using your default (root) Python environment, because it's not aware of your `virtualenv` one. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891550/jupyter-notebook-running-kernel-in-different-env) for details on how to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

If you land here looking for the answer, this is it (taken from the question @Aleksey Bilogur refers):

```
source activate ENVNAME
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name ENVNAME --display-name "Python (whatever you want to call it)"
```

It is really important that you install ipykernel in your virtualenv and that you launch `jupyter notebook` also from you ENVNAME.

Once you've done that, check if the path to your ENVNAME appears when executing from your notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If it does not, something went wrong and it won't work.