# Using development version of package in JupyterHub

Tags: python, module, package, jupyter

I am trying to work on improvements to a pip installed package developed by our team. I am unable to import my improved and additional modules for thoroughly testing before integration into new version. I understand this is likely namespace issues, but i'm unable to resolve them. I've read what I can find, including this excellent [blog on import traps](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html/%22blog%20on%20module%20taps%22).

I am doing my testing and applications for the library methods in Jupyter. In a failed attempt to avoid collision, I have this renamed the top package dir:

```
new_package/
  setup.py
  __init__.py
  new_package_dir/
    __init__.py
    cool_things.py
    dir1/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
    dir2/
      __init__.py
      bar.py
```

i have no main() methods. we are using python 3.6. the package was setup so that the top level __init__.py file contains: from dir1 import * and from dir2 import *.  the other __init__.py files are empty.

in jupyter, i have tried to

```
import sys
sys.path.append('absolute_path_to_new_package_dir/')
import new_package_dir.dir1.foo as foo
```

as well as several other variants. I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new_package'.

appreciate any advice. my problems seems nearly identical to one described in the blog above, except i don't want to execute main(), i want the library available for working in Jupyter.

Comment: shouldn't be: `sys.path.append('absolute_path_to_new_package_dir/')` ?

Comment: corrected @DSLima90 - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now able to answer my own question, by piecing together various other stackoverflow answers and blog posts. In the end, the solution was to:

- create a virtual environment,
- create a development version of the working package within that environment, and
- create a jupyter/ipython kernel for the the environment to use in JupyterHub.

Specifically, this is how I achieved those things and the hiccups along the way:

#### Creating the Virtual Environment

This is all standard conda virtual environments. Install virtualenv. If conda is already installed, use

```
conda install virtualenv
```

pip install will not work in this case. Then create a directory 'virtualenvs' in your home directory to store the environment. The directory name and environment name don't matter.

```
virtualenv ~/virtualenvs/my_env
```

creates a virtual environment, my_env. Now, activate that with

```
source ~/virtualenvs/my_env/bin/activate
```

The prompt will show the new environment.

#### Create Development Package

Navigate to the package you want to develop in and run

```
python setup.py develop
```

In my case, this chugged for quite a long time and gave endless warnings about numpy. I didn't investigate this further because in the end it worked, and it seems others reported similar issues with develop and numpy.

When its done, you should get a message like

```
Using <your_home>/virtualsenvs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Finished Processing dependencies for way-cool-package==0.01
```

You can navigate to that location and confirm existence of an egg.lnk file, and you can also check the package is 'installed' with

```
pip freeze
```

At this point, with the python interpreter you can test that your module is accessible. I added a new print_hello method to my module and then checked that I could import that.  The first time I did all this, I didn't have the order correct, and as a result, python was only importing the site-installed package, not my new enhancements.

We work in JupyterHub a lot, so this wasn't good enough for our team. If you try to use ipython on the command line here, it will nag. Next step..

#### Create Jupyter Kernel

Within the new virtual environment, check if ipykernel module is installed by using pip freeze. Otherwise,

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Create a new Jupyter kernel with the name new_kernel by

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=new_kernel
```

This will install the kernel in your home directory and report

```
Installed kernelspeck new_kernel in <your_home>/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/new_kernel
```

Now, refresh your JupyterHub Notebook, open an new one, and you should have 'new_kernel' as an option.

#### The Last Gotcha

The last gotcha I encountered was in a colleague's package on which I have a dependency. They used __file__ in their code to create their doc string. When trying to use my own modules in the new kernel, I hit a 'NotADirectoryError' which puzzled me. After all, their code was pip-installed site-wide and had no issues. Then, I noticed in the setup tools documentation that instead of using references like __file__, which make an assumption about the path, you should use pkg_resource.resouce_string(). I made that change to their code, and all was perfect.

Here are some of the resources that I used:

- [Beginner's Guide to Clean Python Development Environments](http://tjelvarolsson.com/blog/begginers-guide-creating-clean-python-development-environments/)
- [Using your own kernel in JupyterHub](https://zonca.github.io/2015/10/use-own-python-in-jupyterhub.html)
- [Jupyter notebook running kernel in a different env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891550/jupyter-notebook-running-kernel-in-different-env)
- [Accessing package resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources)