# Keras module not found - Jupyter Notebook ( Windows 10 )

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I know this question has been asked before but I have not been able to fix the issue with the responses, hence posting this one.

I get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

when I import keras.

1) I created a new env ( python 3.5 )  and insatlled tensorflow,theano and keras.

2) I can see the package Keras when I list the packages in this env

3) I tried uninstalling and then install Keras back ( using pip3 as well , as suggested in another forum)

4) I can see keras folder under /site-packages

Not sure what I should be doing to get it to work. TIA.

Comment: Perhaps, Python interpreter in Jupyter may differ from Python you intended.

Comment: Please verify your Python interpreter with `import sys`, `print(sys.executable)` in Jupyter notebook cell.

Comment: @dkato - thank you so much. It was indeed different.

Comment: I used the accepted answer here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891550/jupyter-notebook-running-kernel-in-different-env  . This helped!

Comment: Not at all. Good stuff:)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on a windows laptop.  the other answer didn't help me...  here's what I did to get it working:

first I had to stop using cygwin.   the various commands are a bit wonky unless you are using cmd.exe.

second, I read this article and follow the instructions to essentially install Jupyter within the env I wanted it to play with.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-work-with-Keras-on-a-Jupyter-notebook-using-Tensorflow-as-backend

hopefully this will help someone!