# Module 'instaloader' has no attribute 'Instaloader'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, instagram

I'm trying to use a little script that gets instagram posts on specific period

That's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
import instaloader

# Get instance
L = instaloader.Instaloader()


posts = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE).get_posts()

SINCE = datetime(2019, 4, 1)
UNTIL = datetime(2015, 4, 23)

for post in takewhile(lambda p: p.date > UNTIL, dropwhile(lambda p: p.date > SINCE, posts)):
    print(post.date)
    L.download_post(post)
```

When the script runs just prints this: `module 'instaloader' has no attribute 'Instaloader'`

Yes, I have installed the module.

Comment: Do you have a custom `instaloader` module/package in your project? If yes - please rename it.

Comment: Nope, I haven't

Comment: I see, try to add `print(instaloader)` right after the import to see if the correct module is loaded.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project name is instaloader.py try to rename it in different, because it's the same as lib's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on ipython (Jupyter) or Idle, it is possible that they are using the default python environment and not the virtualenv you run the command from.

For ipython (Jupyter) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv).

For idle use:

```
(venv)$ python -m idlelib.idle file.py
```