# Running jupyter notebook with Keras on a virtual machine from Pycharm

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

After running the .ipynb in pycharm and clicking cancel on the popup that says `Please, enter your Jupyter Notebook URL and authentication token` -> Clicking Run Jupyter Notebook next to `Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook` and copying and pasting the url under `To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:.... Or copy and paste one of these URLs:`

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv) to run the python set up in my virtual machine.

After this, and after installing all modules including Scipy I am receiving this error when training  Keras module

```
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

The module is installed though.

After

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to force reinstall scipy

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy
```

I noticed that there were a few python files that were being read from the wrong path.

The solution involved closing Pycharm, and reopening it. Then when running the .ipynb file again, I had to set Python interpreter and Project to the correct ones. (untitled is the name of the project, and Python 3.6 (untitled) is the name of the venv)

Project was previously set to `username` and `Python Interpreter` was previously set to the python /user/bin/python.

[image]

Project was previously set to `username`(the home directory) and `Python Interpreter` was previously set to the python in /user/bin/python. Because the Project was set to username, I believe some of the scipy files were being read from the home directory. I don't know why this was the case though.