# Always use a Python virtualenv in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to Ubuntu and Python virtualenv. Since I realized the importance of virtualenv, I'd like to use it by default whenever I run python(from installing packages, to using Jupyter) so that I don't need to run source bin/activate every time.

Comment: As it says it create isolated environment of installed python version. If any how you get to manage your way to activate virtualenv by just typing python. Then how will you able to manage separate isolated environment and how it will decide to which isolated environment you wants to use. So I don't think there is need to do this.

Comment: for the mean time, I'd like to only use one environment. And is there a way to always use this virtual environment in Jupyter?

Comment: Okay, checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv

Comment: Checkout pyenv [https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv] even though it version manager it has lot to offer