# ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter while pip freeze shows its installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai

I created a virtual environment, installed pandas and some other libraries, changed the ipython kernel and then opened jupyter inside my virtual environment. Pandas and other libraries worked fine.

Then i installed fastai in my virtualenv, but it shows `ModuleNotFoundError` in Jupyter only. It works fine in terminal, when i run `!pip freeze` inside Jupyter it lists 'fastai', when i try to install it in jupyter with '!pip install fastai' it shows 'Requirement already satisfied' but importing it still gives me 'ModuleNotFoundError'.  [Check this image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhBuv.png)

All answers on SO to this question are for people who haven't changed their jupyter kernel to their environment or who have had other issues, but i couldn't find my issue.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718912/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-scikit) seems reminiscent and has some useful comments. I'll point out that one of the links is old and now there is `%pip install <package>` for use in Jupyter.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: I did the pip install. It says the module is already installed. That is why !pip freeze is showing it. 

@AMC the image was to show people that it IS installed in jupyter and IS showing there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the virtualenv to the kernel. Nice discussion is here ([Execute Python script within Jupyter notebook using a specific virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv)).

Assuming virtualenv is working fine (jupyter-notebook and fastai are working), these are the additional steps, I might have tried. In the second line (below) change the "**--name=NameOfVirtualEnv**" appropriately with the name of your virtualenv.

```sh
pip install --user ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=NameOfVirtualEnv
```

After that once you start the Jupyter notebook, you will see the "New" dropdown to the right side .. there you will have your virtual environment with the fastai.

Please let me know the outcome. Curious if it worked for you.

Comment: As i said, i already did these steps. 
I am inside the virtual env inside jupyter, that is why fastai and other libraries installed in my virtual environment are showing with pip freeze.

Answer (score 0):

`!pip freeze` within a notebook will list the packages inside the environment from which Jupyter was launched, not the selected kernel. This may for example be a system-wide Jupyter installation.

`help("modules")` will list everything available to use by the kernel. I expect you need to install the new package inside the virtual environment (outside of Jupyter), then you will need to restart the Jupyter server, at which point your new package should then be available and listed upon running `help("modules")`.

Comment: For more context for others reading the first paragraph here, the exclamation point alone can potentially send the command off to run in a temporary shell instance that may not be the same place as Jupyter kernel is running. (See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to get a better sense about how the exclamation point use with `pip` and `conda` can lead to issues and confusion). Because of this issue,  ...

Comment: <continued> the magic `%pip` (& related `%conda`) install commands were added to modern Jupyter to insure they run in the environment where the Jupyter kernel is running, unlike the exclamation point. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez)  for more about those commands. So you can use the user-friendly, universal within modern Jupyter (works in JupyterLite, too) command **`%pip install <package>` in a cell**. And I think the use of`%pip freeze` may be better & get what the kernel sees, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Wayne I've just checked and yes, `%pip freeze` will list what the kernel sees.