# Can't access Tensorflow & Pytorch from Jupyter notebook or Lab?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter-lab, python-3.8

I can't access tensorflow or pytorch from Jupyter notebook or lab. My OS is macOS big sur . I installed python@3.8 using homebrew. If I try to run this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)
```

simple code on Jupyter notebook , it is showing this output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3c075791d0d7> in <module>
      1 # TensorFlow and tf.keras
----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 
      4 # Helper libraries
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I created separate virtual environment and install tensorflow on it. But I installed jupyter notebook & lab outside virtual environment. Is there anyway to access tensorflow & pytorch from jupyter notebook or lab without using Anaconda?

Comment: You need to install `jupyter` in the virtual environment.

Comment: @Lescurel sorry brother it is not working at all . Still facing the same problem "ModuleNotFoundError"

Comment: You need to install kernel for jupyter notebook and select the specific kernel before running anything. Follow this post then it should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/